# Perl - removing directory with spaces

Tags: perl, debian

I have some old CGI script which doesn't seem to work correctly.

There is a directory

```
$dir = "schedule/2015/Some Directory/Some Deeper Directory";
```

I use `File::Path`, I also tried using `system("rm", "-rf", $dir);` 
Or `remove_tree($dir)` but I got error that directory doesn't exist and when I do `system("ls -l")` the directory is listed.

Also I tried to cd intro Some Directory and the remove the Some Deeper Directory but with no luck.

Actually when I run it locally on my mac, it works fine, but on Debian squeeze server it fails.

The perl version is 5.010001.

I have not much more information about the server and have only FTP access.

What's your ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `remove_tree` works for me: `dir="schedule/2015/Some Directory/Some Deeper Directory"; mkdir -p "$dir" && perl -MFile::Path=remove_tree -we "remove_tree q{$dir}"`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following, a slight modification of your example above:

```
system("rm", "-rf", "'$dir'");
```

...as long as you're in the right directory (i.e. in the parent directory of `schedule`), although `rm -rf` is always dangerous...

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.

cannot remove ./schedules/2015/Some Directory/Some Deeper Directory: Bad file descriptor at index.cgi line 211.

Comment: Can you post the command you are using to create a sample directory, and then a sample script that fails to delete it.  So far all attempts to recreate the problem have failed, so I suspect either that there is an error in the directory name, or you're in the wrong directory when you run the script.

Comment: Ok, whole issue was because someone created directory "Some directory ", with space at the end and I didn't see it. I noticed that when I tried to rename it. Facepalm.